# Generate Java code from dependent XSDs

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, maven-plugin

In this case I have three XSD files. Where `basic.xsd`provides general objects and`use-case-1.xsd`and`use-case-2.xsd`are both importing the basic objects by:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/app/basic" schemaLocation="basic.xsd"/>
```

I wan't to generate code out of these XSD files having the objects provided by the `basic.xsd`only once. Which maven plugin provides this functionality and how do I have to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

The jaxb2-maven-plugin works.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The plugin defaults to looking for the XSD files in `src/main/xsd`. The xjc goal binds to the `generate-sources` phase. The package names are derived from the namespaces by default. Any imported namespaces will use the objects generated from the referenced schema.